# Assets paths in LESS using Symfony

Tags: symfony, path, less, relative-path, absolute-path

Using Symfony2 and LESS, I'm having a hard time to find a nice way to import assets. E.g, if I want to import an asset in my LESS-file located in `@bundle/Resources/public/css/file.less`, and the asset is located at: `/web/assets/vendor/foo/bar.less` (considering `/` as project root).

Using `../../../../../../web/assets/vendor/foo/bar` works, which isn't very pretty. `/web/assets/vendor/foo/bar` doesn't work either, since LESS doesn't know where the project is located.

Are there any prettier solutions than above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching to [Less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php), and then specifying a `path` in my `config.yml`. Full example:

```
#config.yml
assetic:
    filters:
        lessphp:
            apply_to: "\.less$"
            paths:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
```

Which made it possible to use e.g:

```
@import 'assets/vendor/foo/bar';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly a solution, but may be some inspiration:

I am using assetic filter and sass, and below config is works well

```
assetic:
    filters:
        scss:
           load_paths:
               - '%kernel.root_dir%/some/scss_path'
               - '%kernel.root_dir%/some-other/scss_path'
```

and there is --include-path option if you compiling your less manually:

```
$ lessc styles.less --inlude-path="/web/assets/vendor/foo"
```

are you using less.js ? in production is recommended to use precompiled css. I think assetic is proper solution, especially if you are using symfony. It can compile your less in runtime when you are in development mode, and then can simply use `assetic:dump` to compile all your less for production mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I had to configure a load-path as well. I'm using lessphp with Assetic.